# stop method is not call when implement IRegisteredObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5, background-task, fire-and-forget

I am trying to write one line of log when w3wp.exe is shutting down by IIS.
however i never seen that log appear.

also, i try locally with a dummy asp.net mvc app. 
in controller, i perform a dummy for loop to keep the request going, at the same time i have a copy of below detector

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/ShutdownDetector.cs

```
ShutdownDetector sd = new ShutdownDetector();
sd.Initialize();
```

thinking if i force kill w3wp.exe proecss, should trigger stop mehtod. but no luck.

anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)` in `Global.asax.cs`?

> Parameters 
>       sender 
>           The source of the event. 
>       e
>           A System.EventArgs that contains the event data. 
>   Requirements 
>   **Platforms:**  Windows 2000,
>   Windows XP Professional, Windows Server 2003
>   **.NET Framework Security:**
>  
>       Full trust for the immediate caller. This member cannot be used by
>   partially trusted code.

source : [`Global.Application_End Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee255094(v=bts.10).aspx)

Works fine for me. It will fire when the app pool is brought down, and it's simpler than using `IRegisteredObject`.